# xslt count nodes in grandchild container

Tags: xml, xslt, count, ups-api

Please excuse any mistakes, I only started learning XML 2 days ago.
I have an xml file that gets returned in this format:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <d></d>
    <e></d>
    <c></c>
    <c></c>
    <c></c>
    <c></c>
    <c></c>
  </b>
  <b>
    <d></d>
    <e></d>
    <c></c>
    <c></c>
    <c></c>
    <c></c>
    <c></c>
  </b>
  <b>
    <d></d>
    <e></d>
    <c></c>
    <c></c>
    <c></c>
    <c></c>
    <c></c>
  </b>
</a>
```

I need to count how many `<c>` nodes there are, but I only want to count in the first `<b>` container, the rest are ***always*** exact repeats of the first `<b>` set with different data for `<c>`.  The schema requires it.

Here is what I have right now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <select name="shipping_options" id="shipping_options">
        <xsl:for-each select="/RatingServiceSelectionResponse/RatedShipment">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="Service/Code = 01">
                <option value="01">UPS Next Day Air - $<xsl:value-of select="format-number(TotalCharges/MonetaryValue, '###,###.##')"/>
                </option>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="Service/Code = 02">
                <option value="02">UPS 2nd Day Air - $<xsl:value-of select="format-number(TotalCharges/MonetaryValue, '###,###.##')"/>
                </option>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <option>No Data</option>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </select><br />
    <xsl:value-of select="count(RatedShipment/RatedPackage)"/> total boxes.
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

From what I can find, I think this `<xsl:value-of select="count(RatedShipment/RatedPackage)"/> total boxes.` should be working, but it's returning 0.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to count how many `<c>` nodes there are, but I only want to count in the first `<b>` container

The following XSLT-1.0 stylesheet achieves just that.
It counts the occurrences of the `C` elements in the first `b` element:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="//b[1]">
      <CountOfC>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(c)" />
      </CountOfC>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

BTW: Your posted stylesheet seems to be in no relation your posted XML (???)

Comment: The XML was just as an example of the format.  I probably should have matched the variables in my actual xsl.

Comment: that worked perfectly! thank you for the nice, simple answer!  I knew there had to be something.

Comment: @Alith7: Glad I could help.